# Check downloaded file integrity

Tags: digital-signature, integrity

I am working a lot with vagrant boxes and virtual machines and software outside of the OS repositories.

Scenario:

http://apache.mirror.digionline.de/hadoop/common/stable/

I downloaded the file `hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz`. To check its integrity I need to validate against `hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz.mds`. As **both** files are downloaded via unsecure transport, and the domain is not available via TLS - how does this even work, when the binary **and** the signatures could be faked?

Comment: See if you can find a download mirror that lets you verify the checksum after download.

Comment: A hash is not a signature because nobody signed something. To check a signature you would also need to trust the signer. And when you have a proper signature and the signers certificate TLS does not matter at all. As for the rest of the argumentation see [How can I check the integrity of the downloaded files?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43332), [What security purpose do hashes of files serve?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33154) and [lots of others](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+download+hash) -- marked as duplicate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your comment, that makes sense. I would need the issuers certificate and then it does not matter how the signature itself is transfered, because all of the three (file, signature, certificate) have to match to be valid.