# Should I get an antivirus for Linux Desktop

Tags: linux, antivirus, desktop

On a non-international forum I was reading a discussion about using an Antivirus on Linux Desktops. There are two opinions:

```
1. Anti-Virus is best-practise regardless of the OS used
2. Anti-Virus on Linux does more harm than good
```

Now most of the answers there are primary opinion based. However one argument that keeps getting used is that there is a real danger in having an AV on Linux because it has to run as root.
I personally do not really see why this in itself is such a big security risk, assuming you install a 'legit' antivirus. I am having trouble seperating the opinions with 'facts' about the risks of Linux AV.

What are the real risks of installing an AV on a Linux Desktop?

Comment: See also [Should I get an antivirus for Ubuntu?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63097/should-i-get-an-antivirus-for-ubuntu)

Comment: @Sjoerd feel free to correct me if Im wrong, but this seems to hint more to: Are there virusses for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AV pros:

- Can detect old viruses
- Sometimes can detect recent viruses (depending on vendor detection/update time)
- Sometimes can proactively detect viruses and alert to a suspicious activity

AV cons:

- Do contain bugs (all software does) and run with high privilege level, sometimes exploitable.
- Usually consist of megabytes of closed-source, really complex (parsers for tens of file formats, process monitoring, etc...) code that you run as root.
- Demand trust in vendor, vendor's internal security architecture, vendor-generated SSL certificate for https web AV functionality, ...
- Slow down your system
- Do close to nothing against qualified attacker or targeted attack.

I tried to be objective, but my bias is clear. AV can protect against `CoolPhoto.jpg.exe` email attachments, but if you are advanced enough to run Linux on the desktop then you do not need that protection.

Comment: I think this is a fairly objective post. Given that virtually any programmer can write a virus that is not detected by AV in 10 minutes is testament to the fact that AV is only good for known samples or very, very badly written malware. I [wrote an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/182288/165253) similar to yours on another post, elaborating on the downsides to antivirus (although it was not specific to Linux). I came to the same conclusions you did.