# Where can I configure certificate rules on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, content-security-policy

This excellent [SSO answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/182288) recommends to use certificate rules on Windows’ executables, as [explained here by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/system-settings-use-certificate-rules-on-windows-executables-for-software-restriction-policies). The latter says that the “location” of this setting is:

> Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options

I would like to do so, but I do not manage to find that corresponding control panel on my Windows’ PC (running in German). There is a [German version of that article](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/system-settings-use-certificate-rules-on-windows-executables-for-software-restriction-policies), but the line in question reads basically the same:

> Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Einstellungen\Lokale Policies\Security Optionen

Since it does not start with `HKEY_whatever`, I think it is not a registry entry. But what else?

Computer Configuration − could mean this window?

[image: Computerverwaltung]

But there is nothing like “Windows Settings” in that dialog.

Windows Settings − looks like the caption of the new control panel. But I do not open that from any “computer configuration”, but directly from the start menu.

[image: Windows-Einstellungen]

Security Settings − could be this panel?

[image: Windows-Sicherheit]

Local Policies − nothing like that…

Here is where I am lost. Can you please point me to the setting, maybe with some screenshots so that I can guess on my translated interface where to find that setting?

Comment: Which windows edition? Try Win+R `gpedit.msc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The articles on Windows IT Pro Center are in a hierarchical order, and it is expected that it would be unnecessary to repeat the information provided on previous levels. Your answer is three levels up:

- [Security policy settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/security-policy-settings)

  > Security policy settings are rules that administrators configure on a
  >   computer or multiple devices for the purpose of protecting resources
  >   on a device or network. The Security Settings extension of the Local
  >   Group Policy Editor snap-in allows you to define security
  >   configurations as part of a Group Policy Object (GPO).
  >
  > For more info about managing security configurations, see [Administer
  >   security policy settings.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/administer-security-policy-settings)

  - [Security policy settings reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/security-policy-settings-reference)

    - [Security Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/security-options)

      - [System settings: Use certificate rules on Windows executables for Software Restriction Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/system-settings-use-certificate-rules-on-windows-executables-for-software-restriction-policies#policy-management)

If you are applying this to a **single computer**, your options are:

- Local Security Policy (Win+R `secpol.msc`):

  [image: Local Security Policy]
- Local Group Policy Editor (Win+R `gpedit.msc` as suggested in the comments):

  [image: Local Group Policy Editor]

On a Windows AD domain you'd use the *Group Policy Management* or *Security Configuration Wizard*.