# Hash extension(padding) attack

Tags: cryptography, hash

I recently came across this website talking about sha1 padding attack.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140729003849/http://www.vnsecurity.net/2010/03/codegate_challenge15_sha1_padding_attack/

After reading here are some of my doubts:

1. How do the server side checks the signature? Even after successful
   padding, the sha1 hash is still different from the validate signature
   isn't it?

For example: 
secretkey = key1 
username = shaun
role = 1 
sha1 hash : b7de8c16d9f42394b51e0c1c86c36a4b9bca8d49

secretkey = key1 
username = shaun
role = 0 
sha1 hash : 4e86a40776a282816ee0654cb2ec8a3fb2bd25e5

Can someone please explain to me which part do I get it wrongly? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, the server code looks like this:

```
Incoming value is "X|Y" -> split between "X" and "Y"
Compute id = Un-Base64(X)
Compute h = SHA-1(secret_key + id)
If the hexadecimal value of h is not equal to Y, then deny access
id is "user|role" with "role" being either 0 or 1; so, if id ends with "|0",
grant administrator access.
```

`secret_key`, of course, is unknown to the attacker. But the attacker can try to guess the *length* of that key, if only by trying different lengths; in that example, `secret_key` has length 25 bytes.

SHA-1 suffers from the [length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) (like all [Merkle–Damgård](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) hash functions). See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34492/is-using-md5-sufficient-reason-to-reject-this-payment-processor/34496#34496) for detailed explanations; bottom-line is that by knowing the length of `secret_key`, the attacker can compute a special "id" string like this:

```
id2 = aaaa|1somebytes|0
```

where `somebytes` include the SHA-1 standard padding, and then the attacker can compute the appropriate hash value for that "id", starting with the known SHA-1 value (the one for `aaaa|1`) and *without knowing `secret_key`* (that's the point of the "length extension attack": computing *h(m')* where *m'* starts with an unknown *m*, but with *h(m)* known).

The server will believe the provided "id" string to be genuine, and grant administrator rights to a user named "aaaa|1somebytes".

Comment: Hey, sorry just wondering if hmac was used then this a recommended implementation in the real world?