# Is MD5 ok to use if salted?

Tags: md5

This post:
http://www.gaiaonline.com/journal/?mode=view&post_id=19734573&u=8357925

Said that salted MD5 is ok but regular MD5 would not be ok.
I am a bit confused about this and would apprecaite a response.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Even salted MD5 is comically weak. Don't take advice on cryptography from non-cryptographers.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: That is duplicate question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Answer (score 3):

The solution is garbage because they store **unsalted** MD5 hashes of passwords in the database. That is the weakest link in the solution. Nothing else matters.

Comment: Okay, glad I wasn't imagining things.

Comment: Even if they stored a salted MD5, it would be garbage.