# MySQL AES_ENCRYPT key length

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key-management, mysql, pycrypto

`AES_ENCRYPT` uses a 128 bit long key to encrypt the data, but how MySQL handle longer or shorter keys? I found out that PyCrypto for instances recomend to transform the key by using MD5, SHA-1, SHA-2, etc. hashes and then using the the resulting key for encryption. How does it work with MySQL?

Comment: What is your underlying goal?  Is it critical that you replicate what MySQL does?  Or would you rather do it in a secure way?  See discussion below.

Comment: nope it is just to mimic the internal mysql process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but I found that later from [RubyForum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/182297)

"The algorithm just creates a 16 byte buffer set to all zero, then loops 
through all the characters of the string you provide and does an 
assignment with bitwise XOR between the two values. If we iterate until 
we hit the end of the 16 byte buffer, we just start over from the 
beginning doing ^=. For strings shorter than 16 characters, we stop at 
the end of the string."

```
  bzero((char*) rkey,AES_KEY_LENGTH/8);      /* Set initial key  */

  for (ptr= rkey, sptr= key; sptr < key_end; ptr++,sptr++)
  {
    if (ptr == rkey_end)
      ptr= rkey;  /*  Just loop over tmp_key until we used all key */
    *ptr^= (uint8) *sptr;
  }
```

which looks like that in Ruby

```
def mysql_key2(key)
   final_key = "\0" * 16
   key.length.times do |i|
     final_key[i%16] ^= key[i]
   end
   final_key
end
```

and I applied that to python:

```
finalKey = b'\0'*16
key = b'mySecretKey'
for i, c in enumerate(key) :
  finalKey[i%16] ^= key[i]
```

It's probably wise not to use a repetitive password such as `"MySQL=insecure! MySQL=insecure! "` as it would zero out the resulting key.

Comment: Oh dear - that seems like an awful solution, since it reduces the keyspace.  Pretty typical for mysql though....  You want to use a proper key derivation algorithm instead - see [Key derivation function - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)

Comment: Also note this text from your link: "Please take
into consideration that security is definitely not the goal, talking to that system properly is."  So unless you simply can't convince folks to do security properly, I'd suggest just rejecting the way MySQL does it, the same way you should reject all the ways that MySQL deals with passwords: [Looking for example of well-known app using unsalted hashes - IT Security - Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/looking-for-example-of-well-known-app-using-unsalted-hashes)

Answer (score 4):

MySQL 5.5 does not handle other key sizes. As stated on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html:

> AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() enable encryption and decryption of data using the official AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) algorithm, previously known as “Rijndael.” Encoding with a 128-bit key length is used, but you can extend it up to 256 bits by modifying the source. We chose 128 bits because it is much faster and it is secure enough for most purposes.

I never tried to pass bigger key to MySQL, but I guess it would yield an error or truncate to 128 bits.

I'm not sure if MD5 use it's full codomain because I can't find any proof of that MD5 is a surjection. So I assume that you will get `less`  security by using MD5 hashes since you reduce the set of possible values for your keys. This is still very subjective.

As far as smaller keys are concerned, I guess that `0x1 == 0x00...01` so it is still a valid key.

By the way, I do not understand why you just don't generate key to the given size. If you have some constraints (already existing key you want to reuse, ...) let us know.

Comment: Yep that was my concern in first place, that I would like to use an arbitrary key and I tried much longer keys, yielding valid encrypted data, which is only decrypted by that long key (I also tried to truncated it).

Comment: Actually I found a solution, but I can not post it now... maybe tomorrow :'(

Comment: @M'vy, no, hashing the key material before passing it to AES_ENCRYPT() does not reduce security.  Your statement *"you will get less security"* is not accurate.  The reason is that a good crypto hash function (e.g., SHA1, SHA256) is collision-resistant: while collisions exist, it is computationally infeasible to find them, so the hash function is basically indistinguishable from a surjection for a computationally-limited attacker.  (Minor complication: MD5's collision-resistance is broken, so this proof doesn't apply; but I still don't know of any weakness in MD5-hashing the key material.)

Comment: Well, hashes function are not meant to build password, so collisions does not really interest us. And usually hashes algorithm does not prove that you can always obtain all hashes value ($2^{n} -1$ for n length hashes length). Indeed `less` word is really a subjective as I said. Should be surrounded by big double quotes. Well if we have such proof or surjectivity, I'd be interested to see this. So "less" just mean that if you use hashes for password the cardinal of codomain is less **or** equal to the $2^{n} -1$ of all possible values.But indeed, it can be equal. Thanks for this good comment.

Answer (score 0):

By default these functions implement AES with a 128-bit key length. As of MySQL 5.7.4, key lengths of 196 or 256 bits can be used, as described later. The key length is a trade off between performance and security. [encryption-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in PHP. You need to do the XOR as described by @joecks and remove padding for any encrypted data shorter than 16 bytes as described here: http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97082

Working code:

```
<?php
    $key = 'SomeSecretKeyThatCanBeLongerThan16Bytes';
    $encodedString = [fetched from DB];

    $finalKey = array_fill(0, 16, 0);
    foreach (unpack('C*', $key) as $i => $char)
    {
        $finalKey[($i-1)%16] = $finalKey[($i-1)%16] ^ $char;
    }

    $dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, implode(array_map("chr", $finalKey)), $encodedString, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
    return rtrim($dec, ((ord(substr($dec, strlen($dec) - 1, 1)) >= 0 and ord(substr($dec, strlen($dec) - 1, 1 ) ) <= 16 ) ? chr(ord(substr($dec, strlen($dec ) - 1, 1))): null) );
```